# Dirac delta function mathematical expression proof

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

In a discussion of the second order transitions in graphene this mathematical expression is used.
$$
\left|\frac{1}{\varepsilon + i \Gamma/2}\right|^2 = \frac{2\pi}{\Gamma}\delta(\epsilon)
$$
And I'm kind of confused right now. Can someone prove this equation?

Comment: Which discussion?

Comment: It's about the mechanism of the 2D' peaks in graphene Raman spectrum. There the author split the second order Fermi golden rule with this equation into 4 parts.

Comment: No, that wasn't the question. You should *always* provide a full bibliographic reference to the documents you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's formula is derived from the [Poisson kernel representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function) 
$$ \delta(\varepsilon)~=~\lim_{\Gamma \to 0^+}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma/2}{|\varepsilon+i\Gamma/2|^2}  $$
of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).